# How to see what icon is at a location in a grid Java

Tags: java, jbutton

Basically when a certain point at a grid is the Player icon it will execute a command.
When I run this command I get java.lang.NullPointerException: null.

```
if (arrButton[1][1].getIcon() == Player)
{
    System.out.println("test complete");
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. The question seems unclear as it is now. Can you provide more information/context of what you are doing, what you are trying to achieve and what you have done so far?

Comment: what is the grid? and what is the player?is player primitive ?

Comment: Basically its just a regular grid game. When the player moves abouton the grid the current icon gets set from background to player. So when the player is at the location 1,1 it will do the command, for example preint test complete. basically once im able to see what icons are where on the grid i can do the rest by myself.

Comment: Either `arrButton` is `null` or the element at `arrButton[1][1]` is `null`

Comment: Please provide more context/code but please keep it to a [minimum](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The question might be very clear from you but for us it is very vague. For example, you are comparing `Player` to the `getIcon()` using == but this is only good if both Objects are primitive types as @getlost asks. We do not know how you constructed arrButton and its elements.

Comment: Okay ill try to explain this better.The objective of the game is to collect 3 missle parts, The missles are placed at determined point within the grid. The grid is 11x11. The point 1,1 is set Missle at first. When the player goes to the point of 1,1 it uses setIcon to change it from missle to player. I want to be able to tell when that happens and when it does it will execute my command.

Comment: @Antirob then  arrButton is jbutton?and you can post some code to find your problem

Comment: I attempted to answer your question, please provide feedback i.e comment on my post so that I know if there is something else to do. If my answer answered your question, please accept it by clicking on the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Player moves from one button to another on a button click,

Firstly have a variable (possibly global) to save the player's current position like so:

```
private int playerCurrentPositionX;
private int playerCurrentPositionY;
```

One of your problems is a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. This happens mostly because an object on the line the exception points to is null. In your case and as @MadProgrammer pointed out, it could be `arrButton` or `arrButton[1][1]`. An object is null if it is not yet initialized. So that an object will not be null, we have to initialize it. In your case like so:

```
JButton[][] arrButton = new JButton[11][11];
```

In this case, only the 2-dimensional array of JButtons is initialized. **The buttons themselves are not yet initialized.** We need to initialize them like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrButton.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arrButton[i].length; j++) {
        arrButton[i][j] = new JButton();
    }
}
```

Now, to detect if a JButton is clicked, we add a [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) like so:

```
arrButton[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //this method is executed when a button is clicked.
        //TODO add logic here
    }
}
```

For more info on how to use ActionListeners, see [this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

We get which button was clicked inside the method and use it to save the position of the player:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrButton.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrButton[i].length; j++) {
            if (arrButton[i][j] == button) {
                playerCurrentPositionX = i;
                playerCurrentPositionY = j;

                //you can also detect using i and j if this button/grid has a missile
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More on java swing components [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)